# Nginx not serving static files even with suggested config

Tags: django, nginx

I've seen this question being asked loads of time here but unfortunatelly none of the answers worked.

Basically my site is in Django with Gunicorn and Nginx. The Django part (dynamic stuff) is working fine but nginx can't find the static files.

Static files located in:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 5 django www-data 4096 Oct 19 13:26 findings
```

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/static/findings/'
```

My nginx config:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }
  location = /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/django/static/findings;
  }
  location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/django/findings-app/run/findings.sock;
  }


}
```

In my live website, the static urls get suitably translated in the html source code as:

```
http://<IP>/static/findings/styles/base.css
```

For some reason I just cannot seem to get the syntax right and nginx just doesn't seem to find any of my static files.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is inside nginx logs?

Comment: it's not location = /static, it should be location /static , same for favicon

Comment: @LiquidDeath Works like a charm now. Stupid typos :-P   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, Thanks @LiquidDeath for the answer:

> it's not location = /static, it should be location /static , same for
> favicon

Stupid typos :-)